# Why am I getting that my emacs tags is not a valid tags table?

Tags: emacs, ctags

I just tried generating some tags for emacs by running something like:

```
ctags -e --extra=+q --sort=yes -R /codebase/one /codebase/two /usr/include /usr/include/c++
```

I drop this in some subdirectory of my home directory. And then I navigate to, say, codebase/one and do `M-x visit tags-table` and load that one and it complains with:

```
File /home/palchan/.tags/tags is not a valid tags table
```

why is this not a valid tags table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `--sort=yes` option.

This solved the problem for me with both `ctags` versions 5.8 (latest) and 5.5.4 (distributed with my version of Linux).

You can also try the `ctags` binary that is shipped with Emacs, which is likely in the same directory as the Emacs binary.  Note: the command line options are a little different.

Comment: This worked! Thank you..btw do you know how to set the default TAGS file directory so I don't have to M-x visit-tags-table /home/palchan/.tags/tags every time?

Comment: @PalaceChan `(setq tags-file-name "/home/palchan/.tags/tags")`

Answer (score 3):

Try the -e option 
*-e   Output tag file for use with Emacs.*

Comment: Yes in general, but *obviously* not relevant to this particular question.